# I can't register avrocoder.class to a custom, autogenreated immutable class

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I wrote this simple DF code:

```
CoderRegistry cr = pipeline.getCoderRegistry();
cr.registerCoder(ImmutableFloatRegionsVector.class, AvroCoder.class);
```

but when I ran it, I got this error below. I am following the DF recommendation on how to register coder classes, so I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. (FYI: I can't put the annotation directly on my class as it's an automatically generated immutable class.)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot register Coder class com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.AvroCoder: does not have an accessible method named 'of' with 1 arguments of Coder type
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.CoderFactories$CoderFactoryFromStaticMethods.getFactoryMethod(CoderFactories.java:166)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.CoderFactories$CoderFactoryFromStaticMethods.<init>(CoderFactories.java:145)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.CoderFactories$CoderFactoryFromStaticMethods.<init>(CoderFactories.java:90)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.CoderFactories.fromStaticMethods(CoderFactories.java:72)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.CoderRegistry.registerCoder(CoderRegistry.java:142)
    at com.iai.DeepSearch.setUpPipeline(DeepSearch.java:110)
    at com.iai.DeepSearch.main(DeepSearch.java:65)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.AvroCoder.of(com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.Coder)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2130)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.CoderFactories$CoderFactoryFromStaticMethods.getFactoryMethod(CoderFactories.java:164)
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case, I recommend registering a single instance of `AvroCoder` for your custom class, like this:

```java
cr.registerCoder(
    ImmutableFloatRegionsVector.class,
    AvroCoder.of(ImmutableFloatRegionsVector.class));
```

The technical details are this: When you register a coder *class*, it is expected to be a class where the static methods make it equivalent to a `CoderFactory`, which maps coders for generic parameters to coders for a datastructure - for example mapping a coder for `T` to a coders for `List<T>`. But all you need for your use case is one particular instance of a coder.